# Assembly: segmentation falut

Tags: assembly, att

I have code in assembler at&t which add two numbers:

```
.code32
.data

liczba1: .long 0x00000001,0x00000001,0x00000001,0x00000001
liczba2: .long 0x00000001,0x00000001,0x00000001,0x00000001

.text

.global main

main:

    movl $3, %ecx
    clc

petla:
    cmpl $0, %ecx
    je ostatnia
    movl liczba1(,%ecx,4), %eax 
    movl liczba2(,%ecx,4), %ebx 
    adcl %eax,%ebx
    pushl %ebx
    decl %ecx
    jmp petla

ostatnia:
    movl liczba1(,%edi,4), %eax
    movl liczba2(,%edi,4), %ebx 
    adcl %eax,%ebx
    pushl %ebx
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    adcl %eax,%ebx
    pushl %ebx
    jmp koniec

koniec:
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

When i run it in gdb, i get: 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004000cc in petla ()

Someone know, why?

Comment: Your debugger knows.

Comment: So which instruction is at 0x4000cc? Any why are you using `edi` without initializing it?

Comment: its pushl %ebx. i fixed that already, change edi to ecx

Comment: but i think, problem is that ecx doesnt decrement

Comment: _"its pushl %ebx"_ There are three such instructions in your code.

Comment: in loop called "petla"

Comment: Use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43095779/edit) to update your question if you made any changes to the code.